# Stack Overflow for enterprise

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, stack-overflow-enterprise

I was wondering if it could be possible to get a version of Stack Overflow internal to enterprise (Private Stack Overflow) where just the workers could ask and reply (between themselves. Could something like this be possible?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197549/98786 for details.

Answer (score 30):

[**Stack Overflow for Teams is free for 50 users**](https://stackoverflowsolutions.com/teams-free?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=campaign-28&utm_content=post-1)

If you aren’t familiar with Stack Overflow for Teams, it combines the best features of the Stack Overflow platform with features tailored for teams and companies who need a private knowledge sharing and collaboration platform such as Articles, Collections and integrations. Check out our [Product Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/tour) page to learn more about these features.

With Stack Overflow for Teams being a flexible platform, we’ve seen customers use it for a wide variety of use cases:

- A platform to help onboard new employees
- A self-serve help center to reduce support tickets
- Collaboration and documentation to drive innersource initiatives
- Breaking down silos and driving org wide transformation like cloud migration efforts
- A direct customer support platform
- Enable people who are working towards a common goal, whether a startup or a side project, to develop a collective knowledge base

It is free for up to 50 users.

- No credit card is required to start your Team, and it’s free forever.
- Our Free plan includes ChatOps integrations to Slack and Microsoft
  Teams.
- We have invested in a guided onboarding process to help admins
  and users experience value quickly and efficiently.

We have 3 other paid plans with additional features:

- Basic - includes the same ChatOps integrations as free and offers SSO and additional support options. The maximum number of users is 250.
- Business - same features as Basic plus long-form content (Articles), GitHub, Jira and Okta integrations, the Collections feature, and a usage and adoption dashboard. Unlimited users.
- Enterprise - same features as Business plus additional hosting, securing, and support options.

You can find the most up to date pricing for those plans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/pricing).

If you prefer a more public-facing site, we have [150+ sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) to [**help support your developer community**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/how-can-i-use-stack-overflow-to-support-our-developer-community). But if you cannot find a Stack Exchange site in your area of interest, we have a place where you can propose one. "Area 51" is a community-driven process where groups of experts come together to build new Q&A sites that work just like Stack Overflow. You can [read more about the site proposal process here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Oh, this is _awesome_. I don't suppose it'll ever be open-source, though.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't really matter for your target audience, but when I'm looking for a type of product to purchase, I immediately skip any product that doesn't publicly list a price or a price range.

Comment: sorry to say but you deleted an upvoted helpful answer on this question which contained information about free available clones. Now I understand that might interfere with the commercial intentions but if you don't want to undelete the answer, are you prepared to include the link to [Stack Exchange Clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones)?

Comment: @rene I removed a few meta posts about SO Enterprise that were way out of date. The list of clones was egregious broken with links redirected to other products or software that is no longer supported. But okay, I fixed the outdated information as best I could and restored the post for the clones;  buyer beware, I guess.

Comment: How much does it cost?

Comment: @morpheus I believe pricing depends on the requirements and hosting arrangements needed by the organization, so the best I can do is suggest clicking through to the Enterprise website to request more information.

Comment: fwiw this is a link I found for the curious among us https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-original-pricing-of-StackExchange

Comment: @morpheus "If you have to ask, you can't afford it"

Comment: @Joy can you please ask if someone wants to flip the Staff bit on your userprofile? It is highly confusing to see edits been applied without review by users with less then 2K.

Comment: @rene - we're working on it. I've opened a ticket to get the badge added.

Comment: Ha @Joy we keep poking CMs in the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8802519#8802519) until you've your badge, even if that takes [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514). Cheers!

Answer (score 15):

The [Stack Overflow Enterprise is now available](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326380/98786), but you'd probably have to be a *very* large corporation with a lot of money to get one of those.

However, there are several [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones).

While with them, you have all the hassle of setup and customization, and neither of them is likely to provide an experience *quite* as perfect as the SE platform (on which, after all, dozens of paid developers and designers work full time every day!), some of them look quite nice and mature.