# How can I use Stack Overflow to support our developer community?

Tags: support, faq, outsourcing, product-support

We get a lot of requests from project teams about how they can use Stack Overflow to support their developer communities. How can these organizations (and their users) collaborate with Stack Overflow to have the best possible experience when interacting with this site?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: See also [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions)

Comment: See also [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product)

Answer (score 127):

### Stack Overflow is Great for *Technical* Support

Stack Overflow works really well for technical support, as long as the project team is not trying to outsource their entire customer support channel to our Q&A format. Stack Overflow was created to build a collaborative work of sharing knowledge for the developer community, so issues like bug reporting, feature requests, and generalized discussions do not fit our Q&A format. The company should continue providing this type of support directly through their website.

### Adding Technical Support for Your Product

Adding technical support for your product is as simple as directing your users to ask their technical questions on Stack Overflow. We've had the best results from following the model used by Google Android to support their developers (see [Android Developers: Hello Stack Overflow!](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html)), so we put together a few guidelines to provide the best possible user experience for both our communities:

### Using Stack Overflow to Support Your Developer Community

1. **Start with your support pages**
   When users have a specific question about a problem they might encounter in their day-to-day use of your product, direct them to ask on Stack Overflow. But Stack Overflow should only be ONE of the options available. Links to handle issues like feature requests, bug reports, future-direction discussions, business inquiries, and other customer support issues should be CLEARLY MARKED. These do not fit our Q&A model, so such questions will be quickly closed by the community.
2. **Encourage organic participation**
   Stack Overflow works best when your community is participating in the site organically. Try not to "seed" common questions about your product on Stack Overflow as a way of generating content. Communities can become very sensitive when it looks like a user is staging posts simply to link back to a product or service. It's best when questions are asked out of an actual need and posted by those who are genuinely seeking help.
3. **Internal perspective is invaluable**
   While we have a very active community, there are some questions that can only be answered by an internal team member. You should have active team member(s) making sure these questions get answered. You want to establish your tag on Stack Overflow as THE place to get help with those harder questions.
4. **Give it 24 hours**
   The collective knowledge of your community is a valuable resource, so if you see a question the community can answer… take a step back and let them. The urge for users to show off what they know is a big part of Stack Overflow, so you don't want that "official voice" becoming the final word on every post. Of course, if a question *isn't* getting answered (or you feel you can provide a *better* answer), by all means, answer it. But you want to encourage that self-directed, peer-to-peer sharing wherever you can. The passion of your community will often create the best content, so you don't want your community to become too passive in waiting for someone else to answer the question every time.
5. **Make your presence known**
   Tag sponsorship adds your logo to every question about your product and gives you control over the content of your "tag wiki". Embedding your logo in a tag is a great way to make your activity stand out. Contact our Ad Department for details.
6. **Our Full-Disclosure Policy**
   While we don't generally require product developers to identify themselves in every post, if an employee or representative of your company is touting your product as a great solution to a problem, make sure they are very forthright about their affiliation, always. The community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag such posts as spam. Don't be labeled a spammer. Full disclosure when recommending a product or service usually alleviates that problem.

Comment: As an addendum, "full disclosure" means something like "Though I'm biased (I'm part of the team that made it), I think product XYZ is a great tool for your situation", not a generic post about how XYZ works really well, with a barely-visible "posted by marketer" note hidden at the bottom or in profile text. Also worth noting is that it still has to answer the question -- don't just say that XYZ works; say that it does, why it's a good solution for the question, and maybe even give an example snippet if that's relevant to the question at hand. In short, recommendations have to be answers, too.

Comment: RE: Disclosure. The general idea of disclosure should be to make the affiliation known to everyone looking, not to comply with a forced minimum standard. We're all developers of some kind here, and we tend to frown _heavily_ upon being market to through deception. Remember that its always in your best interest as an answerer to disclose any affiliations as cleanly and straightforward as possible.

Comment: It would be nice if the answer explained how to deal with multiple tags: how to best create/organize the tags about the product: foobar-core, foobar-web, foobar-persistence, etc. Should the product team wait for tags to be created by a first question? Should they create a dummy question for each tag, etc.

Comment: Should this FAQ clarify that SO should only be used for programming-related technical support?  IIRC there have been issues with companies directing customers here for questions that are not developer-related.

Comment: `Stack Overflow works really well for technical support` feels too broad - even with the limitations that come after, there's a lot of tech support cases that are off topic on SO because they are too localized ("X tool is failing with Y error message" etc.)

Comment: Good points. You might also add that (by default), code posted on Stackoverflow is liberally licensed so the company / developers have no real expectation of copyright protection for posted code.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Is "Too Localized" still a thing?  Lately it seems as if the entire SO site is "Too Localized."

Comment: @Pekka웃, "failing with Y error message" is not grounds for being too localized. **At all.** The first thing people do when they see an error message is to search it on Google. There are too many examples of questions with over tens of thousands of views that are the  "error message" kind.