# Reach out to Google regarding Consumer Surveys

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

We seem to have hit another "outsourced" support and this time it's with Google:

[google-consumer-surveys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-consumer-surveys)

[Their site](https://developers.google.com/consumer-surveys/support) says this:

> If you think your problem might be a common issue, please check the Stack Overflow tag first. We constantly monitor this tag for updates and changes. If your question isn't answered, go ahead and ask your question.

Here is a sample of some of the questions that sound like support tickets:

- [Error 503 doing GET operation on survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603830/error-503-doing-get-operation-on-survey)
- [How do I fix 503: Service Unavailable for Billing Transaction Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466196/how-do-i-fix-503-service-unavailable-for-billing-transaction-error)

Can someone reach out?

Comment: This edit shows where the tag was created in a sort-of seed question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35712103/revisions The user might be a good point of contact.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I left a comment for Dan

Comment: @rene Last seen more than 10 days ago, don't hold your breath :)

Comment: if they constantly monitor this tag, would a question with this tag be a way to reach out?

Comment: @Joel we're not that desperate ...

Comment: @DavidG He's just been online 40 minutes ago now

Comment: Reach out for what purpose?  I'm on the GCS team (but until today I wasn't looking at this tag at all).   The folks who are replying to questions on this tag are relatively new to SO.   Anything I can help with?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326374/23528

Comment: @DanielA.White I've looked at that link already but I'm not sure what you want.  Is something being done wrong here?   Please be specific, I'd like to help however I can.

Comment: I think it would help to guide your users who are new to stackoverflow that it's not just a dumping ground for any question. Like the ones above sound like support requests and not directly programming related.

Comment: Agreed.  A few notes: 1) about half the questions on this tag are using it wrong, and that's a clear indication that they aren't coming from our site, they just found the tag on SO directly.  I will get our team to update the tag wiki to show what it is for.   2)  the other half seem like legit SO questions to me (e.g. "I'm calling the API this way and it doesn't work").   3) I will see who owns that page that points to SO and clarify that it should be for programming questions.

Comment: Thank you! Glad to hear you're engaged and willing to grow with us!

Comment: @TM. that sounds nice cause as of now I see that particular tag has no information about what that tag is for.

Comment: @TM. You should add that as an answer, seems like it resolves everything asked here, good stuff!

Comment: @TM. The answers starts with *"Thanks for reaching out"* and contains statements like *"we only..."*  that really sounds like the tag is being used as a support service. Who are "we"? Since stack Overflow isn't Googles official support site, it's out of context. You might want to educate the answerers that this is a Q&A site and not where people reach out for support specifically from Google team. Either the answerer should include "I work at Google" on top of the answer or use "Google" instead of *"we"*

Comment: @TJ the folks who set this up don't know how stackoverflow should be used really, but their intent was to help programmers who are trying to use our API (which is generally the correct usage).   Questioners are using it for unrelated/improper questions though, and they didn't want to just ignore them.   We will try to get a better funnel set up.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm on the GCS team (although not working directly on the API or this tag).

I've updated the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-consumer-surveys/info) with some info to make it clearer what sort of questions it is meant for, as well as to point to our docs.

The [support page](https://developers.google.com/consumer-surveys/support) mentioned in this thread that links to SO is the support page of our API docs, but it looks like non-developers may be finding it and asking other questions, so we're planning to update it to make it more clear that it is for programming questions only.

Lastly, we're looking into what it will take to set up an official product forum for non-programming questions, to drive even more unrelated traffic away from SO.

P.S. Please let me know if you have any feedback!

Comment: Why haven't you made use of a 'sponsored' tag? Are you still deciding on an icon to represent your product?

Comment: @Jeeped Advertising spend is not up to me.  I did mention that it was an option to the folks who are in control of such things.