# A surge of comments/complaints in [pagespeed-insights]

Tags: support, product-support

Google [says](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/):

> Have comments or questions about PageSpeed Insights? Ask your question on Stack Overflow using the [pagespeed-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed-insights) tag.

Apparently there has been a redesign, and in the last hours there is a (yet small) surge of comments and complaints in [pagespeed-insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed-insights) about it, none of which is appropriate for SO.

Please reach out to Google to remove the "feedback" and "comments" part.

Comment: Dangit Google, [they should know better already!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327707/7795130)

Comment: @DavyM I don't think I've heard a single positive story about Google's management. This team probably doesn't even know a Google doc has suggested something like this before.

Comment: It doesn't help that the tag usage guidance doesn't provide much guidance at all. What does an on-topic programming question with this tag look like?

Comment: @BSMP I was trying to figure it out, from what I could glean from the website (I'm not a PageSpeed user), I think that it would have to be a question basically about how to use the API functions. However, maybe we could get the tag's creator [Paul Irish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89484/paul-irish) to help us out with understanding what kind of questions would be on topic?

Comment: Somebody ought to make them an offer they can't refuse.  Like we won't delete the tag when they start indexing SO content again.

Comment: I worked on that doc. Sorry for the spam. My intention was for people to use Stack Overflow for questions that are appropriate to Stack Overflow. It was an oversight that I assumed that they would know that they shouldn't use SO for general questions and feedback. The team is aware of the issue and working on it.

Comment: This is honestly just abhorred. Most legitimate developers will know that they can post an authentic programming question on SO if they are stuck with some programming aspect of practically anything. Funneling all traffic to SO regardless of audience is just a thorough sign of laziness.

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53163571/1709587) question, used by Paul Irish from Google to seed the tag, really deserve closure? I don't use PageSpeed Insights, and I'm not qualified to judge, but it looks to me like it's probably a perfectly valid question. Certainly closing something as "unclear" when it's seemingly unambiguously answered below seems pretty dubious to me.

Comment: @MarkAmery Yes, though not for being unclear (which is not how I voted). His questions asks for a definition of a term used by some random piece of software. It may as well have said "What does 'I'm feeling lucky' mean on the Google homepage?" Yes, Google is a website. No, that doesn't make it on-topic.

Comment: @Michael It seems to me that the "I'm feeling lucky" example would be off-topic on the grounds that Google is general computing software, not specifically for programmers, but that the fact that this is about terminology used by a *programming tool* changes the calculus. Heck, I've asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28963536/1709587) before about the definition of a term used on some random website, and it's now highly-scored and with an answer from a mod. You can make most any question sound off-topic if you describe it in a way that selectively omits its relevance to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Give Feedback section now says:

> Have specific, answerable questions about using PageSpeed Insights? Ask your question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed-insights). For general feedback and discussion, start a thread in our [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pagespeed-insights-discuss).

---

The More Questions section of the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#support) now also says:

> If you've got a question about using PageSpeed Insights that is specific and answerable, ask your question in English on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed-insights).
>
> If you have general feedback or questions about PageSpeed Insights, or you want to start a general discussion, start a thread in the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pagespeed-insights-discuss).

and upon clicking No in the feedback section of the FAQ, the alert that pops up now summarizes the above paragraph.

Answer (score 66):

Oh dang, it's worse than I thought. There doesn't seem to exist any way at all for users to give feedback to PageSpeed Insights. Check out their [Frequently Asked Questions](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#support) page:

[image: At first they recommend asking on Stack Overflow, but then they ask if the page was useful.]

So we're already at this point where they are incorrectly directing traffic to Stack Overflow for basically any question, but then they have a button to indicate if the information on the page was helpful or not. Of course it isn't, so I decided to click "NO"... and I am horrified by the response.

[image: The response to clicking NO is a banner saying "Sorry to hear that. If you need help, ask a question on Stack Overflow and tag it with pagespeed-insights." with a direct link to the pagespeed-insights tag.]

I'm willing to believe that there can be on-topic questions that can be directed here about PageSpeed Insights, but there is absolutely nothing that can be considered "Feedback of the Frequently Asked Questions Page" that should ever be put in a question on Stack Overflow.

Hopefully when Stack Overflow's representative reaches out to this team at Google, they will promptly remove all of these general suggestions to ask a question on Stack Overflow, and instead replace them with something like "If you have a question about // *specific indication of the programming portion of the API* // , you may be able to get help at Stack Overflow. Make sure to read their guide on [how to ask a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can get an effective answer. If you wish to ask a question in another language other than English, there exist Stack Overflow sites in Russian ([Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), Spanish ([Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), and Portuguese ([Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))."

Comment: The Yes and No buttons on the page merely toggle the message boxes for their respective buttons on and off; nothing is sent to Google. I don't understand the point of asking if the page is helpful if they are never going to act regardless of what is selected?

Comment: I wrote that feedback widget. Sorry for the spam. My intention was for people to use Stack Overflow for questions that are appropriate to Stack Overflow. It was an oversight that I assumed that they would know that they shouldn't use SO for general questions and feedback. The team is aware of the issue and working on it.

Comment: @Jo. the feedback is getting sent to Google Analytics, as intended. I just confirmed. I use this data to help triage what docs I need to work on.

Comment: @jpmc26 see my comment above. The data is getting collected properly and I do indeed use it.

Answer (score 54):

I worked on that doc. Sorry for the spam. My intention was for people to use Stack Overflow for questions that are appropriate to Stack Overflow. It was an oversight that I assumed that they would know that they shouldn't use SO for general questions and feedback. The team is aware of the issue and working on it.

Updates:

- 14 November 2018: I've updated the docs. They're in the code review process.
- 16 Nov: Code review complete. Need to deploy the refreshed docs.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the situation and letting us know your action plan, Kayce. While you're revising the doc, could I recommend that you also mention that Stack Overflow is for English questions only? Two of the questions posted in the last couple of days were in Russian, and we can't handle non English questions. However there are Stack Overflow sites in Russian, Portuguese and Spanish that people can be directed to. I've provided a suggested template at the end of my [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376580/7795130) if you'd like to use it.

Comment: Thanks, @DavyM. I will work on incorporating the language guidance that you've mentioned.

Comment: Tip: even people who use Stack Overflow regularly don't know how Stack Overflow works… 

Comment: PageSpeed Insights already has their own group for feedback at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pagespeed-insights-discuss though ?

Comment: @p4guru yes, we were talking about whether or not we still wanted to use that. It's a long story, not very interesting. We are planning on continuing to use that group for now so that the community will have a place for the general feedback and discussion that is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `They're in the code review process.` - https://dilbert.com/strip/2018-11-16 ;)

Comment: @GSerg I wish...

Answer (score 4):

Can we please exercise some thought and restraint when close-voting questions on this tag? I have not used PageSpeed Insights, and I am extremely reluctant to cast Reopen votes in a tag I know nothing about, but a lot of the closures here make me very uncomfortable.

As I understand it, PageSpeed Insights is a tool to help web developers improve page load times. It is literally of zero use to anyone who is not a web developer. That makes it a valid topic for questions here under the ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clause in the Help Center, and should *categorically* rule out the "general computing hardware and software" close reason for any question in the tag. And yet I see that that reason was used to close both https://stackoverflow.com/q/53281521/1709587 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/53283719/1709587.

I also see comments all over the place that amount to complaints that we are not Google's customer support. Here is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53301844/1709587) asking where to find, in the new UI, a bundle of optimised assets that the asker used to know how to download in the old UI. That seems to me like it's basically an answerable question. Yet it gets a comment saying:

> Unfortunately this website is not a Google support page. You have been sent here by mistake that is hopefully being addressed. Please contact Google with support questions.

The complaint that we are "not a support page" is kind of useless and non-specific. We're not a JavaScript support page either, or a Python support page, or a C# support page. So what? It doesn't tell the reader anything about what's wrong with the question. Can we just nuke all of these comments, and leave only ones that actually articulate specific problems with the question being commented on?

I've voted to reopen https://stackoverflow.com/q/53283719/1709587, since it looks to my naive eyes like a perfectly coherent and answerable question, and I can *definitely* tell that the specific close reason that's been chosen to nuke it with isn't valid. I also suspect that [Why is PageSpeed Insights summarizing the page speed/field data as slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53163571/1709587), used to seed the tag, is not "unclear" at all and deserves to be reopened, but since I'm not an expert in the tool I've abstained.

Edit: I take back what I said about the 7zip question. I took for granted, since the asker said it, that it was possible to use 7zip analogously to gzip over HTTP - that is, as a `Content-Encoding` that the response is served with - and that I'd just never encountered it before. However, after somebody protested in the comments that that's not the case, I Googled, could find no evidence of this, and then remembered the [`Accept-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header exists and confirmed that my browsers don't "accept" anything that looks like 7zip and that the registry of [valid codings for these headers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xhtml) doesn't include 7zip. The question was fundamentally confused, my reopen vote was misguided, and now that it's deleted it's right that it stays that way.

But if you're just blanket voting to close everything in the tag, or leaving "we are not a support site" comments, then please, stop!

Comment: I think some restraint may be warranted in asking people to exercise restraint.  While I don't deny that there may be *some* people who would just blanket close and vote on these questions, there aren't all *that* many which would be on-topic here anyway.

Comment: Note from a grammar Nazi (!): the word "literally" is not an intensifier. It means that you're indicating that the normal metaphorical usage of a phrase is not to be used. Since the phrase "zero use to anyone who is not a web developer" does not have a metaphorical meaning, the use of "literally" is confusing rather than clarifying.

Comment: @halfer Hmm. There are a few possible responses I could give to that, but I think I shall elect for the one where I point out, perhaps possibly to your horror if you were not yet aware, that the most popular dictionaries of both British English (see https://www.telegraph.co.uk/education/10240917/Uproar-as-OED-includes-erroneous-use-of-literally.html) and American English (see definition 2 at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literally) disagree with you, and then walk away cackling and rubbing my hands together with deviant, unnatural glee at my own linguistic perversions.

Comment: Urgh, that is really disappointing. You can consider me both humbled and irritated, Mark.