# Merge and synonym [r8] into [android-r8] and [d8-dexer] into [android-d8]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We got a request from Google to rename and remove the following duplicate tags:

- [r8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r8) and [android-r8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-r8)
- [android-d8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-d8) and [d8-dexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d8-dexer)

Here's how I'm thinking to proceed with this:

- Merge [r8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r8) into [android-r8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-r8), and leave [r8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r8) as a synonym
- Merge [d8-dexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d8-dexer) into [android-d8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-d8), and leave [d8-dexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d8-dexer) as a synonym

This can be done easily in one click, without need for the community to do the work. However:

**Folks active / vested in any of these tags:** Will this break anything and/or are there any good reasons not to do so?

I'll leave this question here through the weekend and then get to it at some point on Monday if there are no concerns presented.

Edit: This has now been completed.

Comment: Did you agree on a tag-sponsorship with Google once re-tagged? I hear Google has a good revenue stream ;)

Comment: This will need to be featured and left up for longer if you want to reach the people using these tags. It's unlikely they'll see it over the weekend sitting here like this.

Comment: Based on this logic, `d8` should also be a synonym (even if this tag is not used).

Comment: One could maybe notify the top users in these tags @shizhen (and others). Featuring for such small tags seems not ver productive.

Comment: @Trilarion: I considered suggesting posting a question in that tag on main SO to go see meta for a possibly-significant change involving that tag.  Probably not worth going to that extreme for just making synonyms, though, since that can be fairly easily undone in the short term if it turns out to be an issue once regular users active in that tag notice it.

Comment: Posting a question on main would not be a good solution, @Peter, as the question would be off-topic. What could be done is to find a post by the top users of the tag, and leave a comment alerting them to this discussion.

Comment: @CodyGray: Hypothetically, if it was really critical to get input from regular users in an obscure tag, we could *consider* bending the rules by making an off-topic question (and locking it so discussion doesn't happen there, and deleting it after a week).  As I said, that level of rule-bending / breaking is nowhere near justified *for this* because it's something we can revert if it turns out to be a problem.  Or yeah pinging people in comments works, too.

Comment: @rene the fact that you were so close to the truth is a bit scary ;)

Answer (score 7):

> Folks active / vested in any of these tags:

I don't really think there is anyone that this applies to. In the last month, the most anyone has answered in any of these tags is once [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r8/topusers)] [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-r8/topusers)] [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/d8-dexer/topusers)] [[4](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-d8/topusers)]

I would speculate that few very people, maybe no one, actively follows any of these. The more established users with points in this tag seem to be mostly [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) followers. The fact questions were also tagged with these was likely incidental.

Your proposal sounds perfectly acceptable. I wouldn't have even bothered posting on meta, honestly. This is a minor housekeeping task.

I seem to remember Google having a history of trying to outsource their tech support to Stack Overflow

- [Reach out to Google regarding Consumer Surveys](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327707/reach-out-to-google-regarding-consumer-surveys)
- [Google are sending YouTube tech support (upload quota) queries to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345938/google-are-sending-youtube-tech-support-upload-quota-queries-to-stack-overflow)

Hopefully this is not to become the destiny of these tags as well.