# ckeditor telling people "Please head to StackOverflow for support"

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

Does SO still want things like this reported? If yes, then am I doing this right?

I know there have been other meta posts about talking to these transgressors in the past.

[image]

https://ckeditor.com/old/comment/129855

Comment: They should have read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/how-can-i-use-stack-overflow-to-support-our-developer-community/326375#326375 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product

Comment: The blog post linked to the "read only" message seems to explain a lot of info (https://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-Community-Forums-Move-to-Stack-Overflow/)

Comment: So...they are playing by the rules?

Comment: If anything the *support* might need an edit, maybe: *development support* or *support with the use of our API*

Comment: The blog appears to be doing the right thing, but they could probably spell _Stack Overflow_ (with the space) correctly. Not sure if it'd be worth reaching out to them for that...

Comment: It's OK in itself to use Stack Overflow for mutual user support. However, I think it's helpful for product owners to clarify that messages posted on SO are seen by general volunteers, messages should not be addressed to a helpdesk or product support channel, and there should be no expectations of a speedy answer, since we're not that support channel.

Comment: They could have, at the very least, spelt it correctly.

Comment: @rene: While not technically incorrect, the term "support" has a certain [false] connotation.

Comment: @Tas: That's really common and I've never been able to determine why. How hard is it?!

Comment: Nice to see (from their blog page) that their intentions are spot on though. I think the banner could use a little tweaking but generally don't see any problem here.

Comment: Of course the questions must be up to [so]'s quality standard. If they are, then no problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because [that's how the staff referred to it, at least semi-frequently, for yeas](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/).

Comment: Wow you are making a big deal out of people using the this site for what it is meant for.

Comment: I am with @JGallardo with that, we all head to Stack Overflow for support.

Comment: @JGallardo if by that you mean to answer questions about "problem[s] that is unique to software development", then yeah, otherwise no.

Comment: As an example, the question linked to surely would get closed for being too broad (even if it's basically a "yes/no" question).

Comment: @JeremyBanks: .........oh.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ["spelt"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelt) you mean "spelled" :op

Comment: @phuzi: I mean [exactly what I said](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spelt#Verb).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok, fair enough. Upon further investigation I was wrong and "spelt" is perfectly valid.

Comment: @phuzi: Nice try though :)