# Create a tag for questions about the Iroha project

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-process

I represent a team that works on Iroha - framework for permissioned distributed ledgers: https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha

There are questions people ask about the project on Stack Overflow and we would really like to help them (and not after 9 months) - and the most convenient way to find those would be by following a tag: [hyperledger-iroha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyperledger-iroha)

Could any prominent member help us with that please?

Upd.: Following your advice, I checked the page with requirements and I see that a short description is needed. I believe the following would be appropriate:

> Hyperledger Iroha is a permission-based blockchain platform with Byzantine fault-tolerant consensus: https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha

And also the questions to which it might be added:

- [Data types of able to process in hyperledger iroha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657121/data-types-of-able-to-process-in-hyperledger-iroha/52442555#52442555)
- [Hyperledger on iOS/Android mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900826/hyperledger-on-ios-android-mobile-devices/52443357#52443357)

Comment: See [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/7296893). There's a short list in there of information you should provide when requesting a tag to be created.

Comment: Are there questions asked on the site about your framework?

Comment: @Braiam yes, I looked for them when I wrote my answer.

Comment: @yivi:  I'm not seeing a problem with either question that was posted, honestly.  Questions which deal with more specifics about a library are still on-topic provided that they're not otherwise overly broad, and I'm not seeing anything that would cause me to immediately think that those questions are overly broad.

Comment: Tag excerpts (and wikis) should be primarily about how to use the *tag*, not what the product is. In other words, when should I use `hyperledger-iroha` as opposed to `hyperledger` or just `blockchain`.

Comment: @Makoto I had posted my comment in haste, I hadn't realized there were two questions. I do think the first one is kinda poor.

Comment: Please also remember to disclose your affiliation with the product you are posting about. [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Answer (score 9):

The biggest issue I see with a new tag being created for this is content curation.  You yourself don't have enough reputation to handle some of the more basic post moderation abilities (closure, downvoting, unrestricted editing), and I don't see any indication that the rest of the team who also uses Stack Overflow would as well.

We (as in the community) can only do limited moderation but it would be best to have someone from your project be capable of handling that level of curation.

Check out [How can I use Stack Overflow to support our developer community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326374/1079354) for more tips on this matter.

Comment: Hi! I definitely get the concern and actually contacted the team before writing to you. Unfortunately, noone of the team is a devoted Stack Overflow'er and it was decided that I could stay in touch with people who ask questions nonetheless. As it is stated in the manual you mentioned, Stack Overflow is, indeed, not the main place where we communicate with the users - but questions get posted here and we just wanted them to be properly tagged and kept in order. Since there are some that cannot really be answered by the general community just yet

Comment: I understand your points about content curation, but isn't that going to be a problem regardless of the tag being created?

Comment: I agree with @g00glen00b, users will post questions on Iroha, whether or not the tag exists. It seems like Sara G and other members from her team try to answer the questions and I guess it would help them to create the tag to find the relevant ones. This way, they would faster gain reputation enabling them to use advanced moderation abilities.

Answer (score 6):

Given that 90% of [these Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=iroha+software&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us) are about your exact software, and there doesn't appear to be much ambiguity when searching for "iroha" on SO, I would simply name the tag [iroha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iroha). Your software seems to be the only one with that name right now.

A lot amount of well-known frameworks have developers that use this site—having tags for their technology helps them out greatly.

On the other hand, I also note that there is an existing [hyperledger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyperledger) tag, but there are also tags for other individual products.

So, I'm in favor of having a tag for this—but I'd like to get community agreement before I create it.