# Is stackoverflowsolutions.com a part of Stack Overflow Inc.?

Tags: support, swag

I received an email telling me I've earned some Stack Overflow swag. Great! But the link in the email takes me to a request form hosted at https://stackoverflowsolutions.com.

This site *looks* pretty legitimate, but it's throwing me off that it's a different domain. I am also surprised, if the site is legitimate, that there doesn't seem to be any reference to it from any page on stackoverflow.com that I can see.

What is this site's relationship to stackoverflow.com? Is it officially a part of the same company? Possibly a separate (but approved) 3rd party? Or something else?

Comment: It appears [it's registered to Stack Exchange Inc.](https://whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflowsolutions.com), and was registered two years ago, but I share your skepticism.

Comment: [yes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326380/6296561)

Comment: If it is not the SO, they have no legal way to know your mail address, and connect it to your SO account.

Comment: Most of the references from Stack Overflow proper are in the case studies section of Teams: https://stackoverflow.com/teams/customers - I'm not sure we ever linked to any of the Talent content there publicly. They were mostly linked in client newsletters and by sales reps.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes - for the time being, swag requests are being handled through this website - you can see it mentioned in the post about swag on Meta Stack Exchange - [Swag is coming back!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back)

This is our UI for granting swag to the users who qualify by reaching 100k, 250k or by being elected as a moderator on one of our sites. I do recognize and understand your hesitance but, in this case, the link and the website are legitimate!

Congrats on your achievement and enjoy your swag!

---

In 2022, we will be changing our system for swag fulfillment and we likely will not be using this method when sending swag at that point.

Comment: I would be much more inclined to participate if there was a means of accessing the swag link via my logged-in account. As things stand, I don't want to give my details to some company that happens to have emailed me.

Comment: @AndyTurner As I said, we'll be changing this in the future but I don't know what it will look like - I certainly agree that an on-site landing page that uses your SO login would be nice. We also don't want people to think that we're adding these details to our own database, though, so we need to be cautious - we don't want people to think that filling in a swag form will give any employees access to your personal information.

Comment: You should have registered swagoverflow.com instead :)

Comment: @Lundin I will add that to the list of considerations, too. :D